# Prove/Disprove $E[X|\mathscr G] = X$ if $X$ is almost surely constant.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, characteristic-functions, almost-everywhere

$E[X|\mathscr G]$ is any (bounded or integrable or something) random variable $Z$ s.t.

1. $Z$ is $\mathscr G-$measurable
2. $$E[X1_G] = E[Z1_G]$$

If $Z=X$ and $X=c1_A$ where $P(A)=1$, then it looks like $Z=X$ has $(2)$ covered but not $(1)$. If that's the case, please give a counterexample. Otherwise, how does it have $(1)$ covered?

Comment: @Michael What formal argument is there other than a counterexample?

Comment: I erased my comment just before you responded.  The reason I erased was because, before giving a formal argument, you need to clarify what problem is being solved here.  You give $X=c1\{A\}$, but you do not specify what your $Z$ is.  In short, what does "$X$ has (2) covered" mean?  Also, defining the random variable $X=c1\{A\}$ a.s. is too vague for this context. Why not just define it surely?

Comment: @Michael Um, edited?

Comment: Your definition of $Z$ is unclear since you give the "a.s." at the end.

Comment: So now you want to pick an $A$ such that 1 fails.

Comment: @Michael Edited again. Well if it's surely then there's no question to ask, I think. Constant random variables are always $\mathscr G-$measurable

Comment: @Michael Oh, do I just pick $A \notin \mathscr G$? I was looking for an explicit counterexample

Comment: The random variable $c 1_A$ is not constant (unless $A$ happens to be the entire sample space).  There is no reason to introduce "a.s."

Comment: @Michael Oh right thanks

Comment: I suppose if you wanted a more explicit counterexample you could define your sample space $S = [0,1]$ and define $\mathcal{G}$ as the trivial sigma algebra with 2 sets $\{\phi, S\}$. So it should be easy to pick an $A$.

Comment: @Michael Let $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$ be our probability space.

Choose $\omega \notin A$, $A \in \mathscr F$ and $\mathscr G = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$.

Then $$E[X | \mathscr G] = E[X] = P(A) = 1$$

but $$X = 1_A = 0$$

? Then again if $\omega \notin A$, then $E[X | \mathscr G] = E[0 | \mathscr G] = 0$?

Comment: @BCLC Your last comment is not correct. "if $\omega \notin A$, then $E[X | \mathscr G] = E[0 | \mathscr G] = 0$" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @d.k.o. because X isn't random there?

Comment: @BCLC So you want to argue that $\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}](\omega)=\mathbb{E}[X(\omega)\mid\mathcal{G}]$?

Comment: From Lebesgue point of view. )), this can be correct, as the non-measurability on finitely many points (or on any set with 0 size), can be ignored, in some sence. However it is reasonable to state a.s. . You can organize your counterexample, with for example non-Borel set, if your sigma-algebra is Borel one, and let $X$ be defined on that non-Borel set as well it. (It is known that there exists a set which is Lebesgue-measurable but non-borel.). So taking the larger sigma-algebra to be the collection of all subsets (which can be done due to Zermelo-Fraenkel), you will be done.

Comment: @BCLC : I thought you completed the problem in your comment "Oh, do I just pick $A \notin \mathcal{G}$"?  Your remaining comments seem to be making the problem harder than it is.  There is no need to introduce $\omega$.  If $c\neq 0$ and $Z=c1_A$ then the event $\{Z=c\}$ is equal to the set $A$.  To violate 1, you just need $A$ with $P[A]=1$ and $A \notin \mathcal{G}$.  If  $\mathcal{G} = \{S, \phi\}$, then it is easy to find such: Don't choose $A$ to be the empty set, don't choose it to be $S$. Of course you need $A \in \mathcal{F}$ so that $P[A]$ makes sense.

Comment: Hopefully it is now clear why the "a.s" in the attempt "$Z= c1_A$ a.s." would not make any sense for this problem, as, due to the ambiguity, we could not determine the set $\{Z=c\}$, and hence could not determine whether or not 1 holds.  If $Z=c 1_A$ a.s., then $Z$ might very well be the constant function $c$, so the event $Z=c$ is the same as $S$, which is in every sigma-algebra.

Comment: @d.k.o. well I guess that's wrong since X is not random in the conditional expectation. So for some $\omega$'s we don't have equality but actually those $\omega$'s collectively are too small to matter so actually $E[X|\mathscr G] = X$ almost surely but technically $E[X|\mathscr G] \ne X$?

Comment: @Michael wait actually is it wrong to say that $E[X|\mathscr G] = X$ a.s. if X is a.s. constant? I think: LHS = 1, RHS = $1_A$ so $1 = 1_A$ almost surely.

Comment: In general, it can be proven that all instances of $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ differ by a set 
of measure zero.   If the constant function $c$ is an instance of $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$, 
then all other instances differ from this constant function by a set of measure 0,
and hence it is indeed true that “$E[X|\mathcal{G}]=c$ almost surely,” regardless of 
what particular $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$  instance you are talking about.

Comment: @BCLC If $X=c$ a.s. for some constant $c$ and is not $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, then $X$ is not a version of $\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]$. In this case, however, $\mathbb{E}[X\mid \mathcal{G}]=c \quad \mathbb{P}\mid_\mathcal{G}$-a.s. (i.e. it is any r.v. which differs from c only on $\mathbb{P}\mid_\mathcal{G}$-null sets).

Comment: @d.k.o. why the restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-field. Suppose $X=c$ almost surely. Then $E(X|\mathcal{G})=c$ almost surely.

Proof. All we need to show is that the constant variable $Y=c$ is a *version* of $E(X|\mathcal{G})$.

- First of all, $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable.
- For any $A\in\mathcal{G}$, we have 
  $$
  \int_Ac\ dP=\int_A X\ dP
  $$
  since $X=c$ a.s.

Q.E.D

---

[Added:] Note that the equality $E(X|\mathcal{G})=X$ should be understood as
$$
E(X|\mathcal{G})=X\quad a.s.
$$
which means $X$ is equal to a version of $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ *almost surely*. But $X$ itself does not have to be a version of $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ and thus does not have to be $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

---

[Added later] Suppose $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is a probability space and $X=c$ almost surely. Then by definition $P(X\neq c)=0$ and if one defines
$$
A=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)= c \}
$$
then indeed, $P(A)=1$ and $X=c1_A$ *almost surely*. But there is no guarantee that $X=c1_A$, (which means $X(\omega)=c1_A(\omega)$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$, )because although $X=c$ on $A$, $X$ could be *not* zero on the complement of $A$.

Comment: Thanks Jack, but I'm not sure you directly answered my question. If $X$ is a version of E[X|G] then it seems to follow that $X$ is G-meas which it isn't...?

Comment: do you disagree with Michael?

Comment: OK. I see your point. I will come back later to clarify it.

Comment: Michael clarifies in his answer that your interpretation of $X$ being constant almost surely is incorrect.

Comment: Oh so versions of conditional expectations are almost surely equal to each other but are free to be almost surely equal to things that aren't versions of such conditional expectations? Thanks Jack! ^-^

Comment: @BCLC: Yes, now you get the idea.

Comment: wait why is X not a.s. constant? Because C could be 0?

Comment: @BCLC: I don't understand what you are asking about.

Comment: 'interpretation of $X$ being constant almost surely is incorrect'?

Comment: I will come back later to edit my answer.

Comment: I don't get notified of edits. I didn't say $X=C$ a.s. I said $x=c1_A$...?

Comment: you wrote in your title $X$ is almost surely a constant. and it is not correct in general that $X=c1_A$ for some $c$ and $P(A)$.

Comment: OH RIGHT THANKS! But if $X$ is a.s. constant then there exists c and A s.t., a.s., $X = c1_A$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sequence of subquestions, can you answer these?  I suspect that your work on these subquestions will make any of your residual confusions disappear. I think the necessary hints for these subquestions have already been given in one or more comments above. So, this will also be a good chance for you to process those comments.

---

Let $\Omega=[0,1]$.  Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the usual Borel sigma-algebra and let $P$ be the usual probability measure that defines, for each set $B \in \mathcal{F}$, the probability $P[B]$ equal to the usual measure of set $B$ on the unit interval.  Define the trivial sub-sigma algebra $\mathcal{G} = \{\phi, \Omega\}$.

a) Give an example of a set $A \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $P[A]=1$ but $A \neq \Omega$.

b) Fix $c>0$. Let $A$ be the set from part (a). Define the random 
variable $X = c 1_A$.  Argue that $X$ is not $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

c) Conclude that the random variable $X$ of part (b) is not a version of $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$.  [I believe this concludes your original question.]

d) Argue that $X=c$ almost surely.

e) Define the constant random variable $Z=c$. Prove that $Z$ is a version of $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$.

f) Argue that if $W$ is a version of $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$, then $W=c$ almost surely.

g) [related to the last d.k.o. comment] Argue that if $W$ is a version of $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$, then the event $\{W \neq c\}$ is in $\mathcal{G}$. Also, $P[W \neq c]=0$.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Usual is Lebesgue?

Comment: Yes. $P[(1/2, 1)]=1/2$.

Comment: A) [0,1) B) [0,1),{1},$\notin$ G C) by def, D) 1=1A, E) check def of cond exp, F) follows by a.s. uniqueness of cond exp

Comment: Wow, that was fast.  I added a part (g) that is related to teh last d.k.o. comment. [I assume your answer in part (D) means "$1=1_A$ almost surely"]